# How do I create a .jar without main in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I am new to Java and IntelliJ and I would to know how to create a jar without a main. I am going to use this jar in other software (like matlab).

My question is similar to this one:
[How to create .jar from specific package (without main) in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288664/how-to-create-jar-from-specific-package-without-main-in-netbeans)

However, I work with IntelliJIdea 12 Community edition, not with netbeans.

Comment: possible duplicate [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

Comment: The part "without a main" is very important. Therefore, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by no main class. I have had no problems making a jar with no manifest.