# Exclude packages while generating sources jar in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-source-plugin

I would like to generate a sources jar but without some packages in my project.

Now I have this in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How to exclude specific packages?

[similar but with netbeans environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288664/how-to-create-jar-from-specific-package-without-main-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the [`maven-source-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) with the [`excludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#excludes) attribute:

> List of files to exclude. Specified as fileset patterns which are relative to the input directory whose contents is being packaged into the JAR.

A sample configuration where you would exclude every class under the package `com.my.package` would be the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/my/package/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it's not excluding the packages I define;
is it a problem to define the package like com.my.package/**

Comment: @jam Yes it is a problem, you need to use the slashes as they refer to the files on disk.